# the_post_thumbnail issues

Tags: php, functions

I am trying to make the thumbnail for each post display on the homepage of a site for a client; although the thumbnails do display, they're not being displayed inside of a specified "thumbnail" div and i cannot figure out why.

You can see the issue yourself here; http://roswell.n8geeks.com. As you can see, the thumbnails are being displayed at the top of the article but should be displayed inside the thumbnail div.

**The code**

```
function Last5posts()   {
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'cat' => '3');                  
    $last_5_posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while($last_5_posts_query->have_posts()) : 
        $last_5_posts_query->the_post();
        $link = get_permalink();
        $title = get_the_title();
        $date = get_the_date();                              

        $content .= '<div class="latest-posts">';
        $content .= '<div class="thumbnail">' .the_post_thumbnail("home-post-thumbnail"). '</div>';
        $content .= '<h3><a href='.$link.' target="_top">'.$title.' / '.$date. '</a></h3>';
        $content .= '<p class="excerpt">' .get_the_excerpt(). '</p>';
        $content .= '</div>';
    endwhile;

return $content;
}

add_shortcode('Last5Posts', 'Last5posts' );
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail()` prints the HTML immediately. Use `get_the_post_thumbnail()` instead to get the HTML into your string.

```
$content .= '<div class="thumbnail">' 
    . get_the_post_thumbnail( null, "home-post-thumbnail") 
    . '</div>';
```

Comment: Thanks, but the thumbnails now no longer display. Any ideas?

Comment: @NikkiMather Sorry, had a mistake in my example: the first parameter should be `NULL` or the post ID. Corrected.